# Generating visual maps in web applications

Tags: javascript, html, django, user-interface, web

For a component of my web application I need to generate visual maps somewhat similar to this:

[image].

I was wondering what I could use in order to do this?

I'm using django and bootstrap.

Comment: You might have to use an interactive API library such as http://openlayers.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SVG** (for drawing) and JavaScript (for animations and interaction) to generate such maps.

Here's SVG tutorial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial